# Want to display an image

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, django

I am having a slight problem. I want a django app that can upload and display an image. Currently, it can upload the image but I cannnot display that image.

So for example, {{comment.photo}} will print out the path `C:/Users/AQUIL/Desktop/myproject/images/P1000992.JPG`. But I want to see that image on the screen. Not the path. How do I print out the image to the screen?

Here is some information that may help.

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='C:/Users/AQUIL/Desktop/myproject/media/images', blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    comments = None
    try:
        comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-datetime')
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'comments':comments}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 


def add_notes(request):
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            comments.datetime = datetime.now()
            form.save(True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(home))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'form':form,'comments':comments}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**home.html**

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}

    <H2>List of Comments</H2>
    <div style="overflow:auto;padding: 10px; border:1px solid black; height:150px; width:700px;">

        {% for comment in comments %}
            {{comment.photo}} <br/>
            <b>Posted by: {{ comment.name }} Date: {{ comment.datetime.date }} Time: {{comment.datetime.time}}</b><br/>
            <div style="font-size:125%">{{ comment.note }}</div><br/>   
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

**form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}    
{% block content %}

<h3>Add Notes</h3>  
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""  method="POST">

{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{form.as_table}}
<br/>
        </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" STYLE="background-color:#E8E8E8; color:#181818 "/>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% if comment.photo %} <img src="{{ comment.photo.url }}" alt="Photo" /> {% endif %}
```

See Geoffrey's comment for how to upload the image correctly.

Comment: I get this error `Caught ValueError while rendering: The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it`. The photo attribute there error is talking about is in `{{comment.photo.url}}`

Comment: put it in and if e.g {% if comment.photo %} {{comment.photo.url}} {% endif %}

Comment: Did you not upload a photo for some of the comments?

Comment: I am not really sure what is wrong now. `@JamesO` If I do what you say it does not print out the image which I guess means it can't finding the image. It prints `img src="/media/C%3A/Users/AQUIL/Desktop/myproject/media/images/P1010088.JPG" alt="Photo" />` Now my images when they get uploaded are stored in `/myproject/media/images/`. I wonder if it can't find these images.

Comment: in your model upload_to should also be relative to your media_root/url - try changing it from 'C:/Users/AQUIL/Desktop/myproject/media/images' to 'images'

Comment: @everyone: It works now. I will have to try and fix the image size myself. The key was having 'images' in my models. Also my img tag was not correct as well. As for a bonus does anyone know how to control the size of the image to upload? That will be very usefull.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765016/django-easy-thumbnails-max-size for one way to control the image size if you use easy thumbnails.

Answer (score 4):

The upload parameter of ImageField must be a local path, so replace:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='C:/Users/AQUIL/Desktop/myproject/media/images', blank=True, null=True)
```

by:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

Then set the MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py as:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/AQUIL/Desktop/myproject/media/'
```

Finally your image 'myImage.png' will be accessible at:

```
C:/Users/AQUIL/Desktop/myproject/media/images/myImage.png
```

And this tag should load the image:

```
<img src="/media/images/myImage.png" alt=""/>
```

depends of your MEDIA_URL in settings.py which should be:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then `{{comment.photo}}`

use `{{comment.photo.url}}`

see sample in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)