# Problems using Django's ImageField

Tags: python, django

I defined the following model:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null= False, unique = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null= False, unique = True)    
    price = models.ForeignKey('Type')    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

I use the following parameters on settings/py:

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
MEDIA_ROOT = '/my/files/root/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The file is properly uploaded in:

```
/my/files/root/images
```

However, I reference it like this:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ pizza.image }}"></img>
```

... and the link is broken.

The link shows:

```
/media/images/imagename.jpg
```

What can I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{{ pizza.image.url }}
```

Comment: ValueError at /menu/

The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: Something wrong with paths [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777732/want-to-display-an-image)